# how to integrate kotlin with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, kotlin

I'm new in kotlin and found that we can integrate JavaScript with kotlin but I'm not able to understand how I can achieve this with the nodejs and kotlin.

I found that I can use the [javaScript with kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html) 
but not able to setup kotlin with javascript.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Use JavaScript in a Kotlin program? Use Kotlin For what platform (server, android)? Or are you trying to use Kotlin in a node program?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your app in kotlin then compile it to JavaScript and then run it with node

Here is example project on GitHub:
[Node js Todo app written entirely with kotlin](https://github.com/techprd/kotlin_node_js_seed)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you only need to compile to js.

Check this [example project](https://github.com/techprd/kotlin_node_js_seed).

Look at the simple configuration via `build.gradle.kts` files (note that there are more than one, check the sub-directories):

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.js") version "1.5.10"
}

group = "com.techprd"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    js {
        browser()
        nodejs()
    }
}
```

Load the JetBrains plugin and specify the target JS platforms (browser & nodejs).

Profit!

**EDIT:**
I figured out just afterwards, that the project is from @techprd.com below!
Don't forget to show them gratitude!